# Can a USB drive be tracked?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

If I had a specific USB and I plugged it into one computer to download something and then plugged it into another computer to download more files/view the files/etc., would there be some kind of record that it was that specific USB plugged into both computers? If someone really wanted to know where that USB has gone, could they somehow find a way to figure out every device that USB has been plugged into?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default" tracking in most computers, however it is perfectly *possible* for the host filesystem/OS to write some form of metadata for tracking. If a drive is plugged into the same system multiple times, there is a record of it being plugged in (in kernel/udev logs for Linux and in the registry for Windows, however that's not cross-system.